# Setting pointer to the return value of a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to set the variables **char * vowels** and **char * consonants** as the return value of the functions searchVowels and searchConsonants respectively.

Although when I test the code, the above variables are getting set properly but not being passed back into the main. And during a test with

```
cout << "text vowels" << vowels << "sametext" << consonants; ///something like this.
```

it doesn't display the consonant value now.

Here's my code, any suggestions would be super helpful. Except that I can't use strings.(For a class)

Also is this the appropriate way to post code?

```
 #include <iostream>                                                             
 #include <cctype>                                                               
 #include <cstring>                                                                   
 using namespace std;                                                                                                                                         
 const int SIZE = 7;                                                             


 //This function greets the user.                                                
 void greetUser();                                                               

 //This funcion asks for the array of letters.                                   
 char * inputLetters(char * inputArray);                                         

 //This will capitalize all letters to make them easier for the computer         
 //to compare.                                                                   
 char * capitalizeLetters(char * inputArray);                                    

 //This function will search the array for vowesl. If no vowels no game.         
 char * searchVowels(char * arrayCopy);                                          

 ///This function will search the array for consonants.                          
 char * searchConsonants(char * arrayCopy);                                      


 //This capitalizes all the letters in the initial array.                        
 char * capitalizeLetters(char * inputArray)                                     
 {                                                                               
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)                   
                    {                                                                       
            inputArray[i] = toupper(inputArray[i]);                         
    }                                                                       
 //      inputArray = toupper(inputArray);                                       
    return inputArray;                                                      
 }                                                                               


 //This program will search the array for consonants                             
    //and return the consonants array.                                      
 char * searchConsonants(char * arrayCopy)                                       
 {                                                                               

    char * consonants; consonants = new char[SIZE];                         

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)                                             
    {//I feel like I could make this into a function itself...hmm           
            if( arrayCopy[i] != 'A' && arrayCopy[i] != 'E'                  
            && arrayCopy[i] != 'I' && arrayCopy[i] != 'O' &&                
            arrayCopy[i] != 'U' && arrayCopy[i] != 'Y')                     
            {                                                               
            consonants[i] = arrayCopy[i];                                   
            }                                                               
    }                                                                       

 return consonants;                                                              

 }
```

Comment: There's so much wrong here. It looks like you're using C++, but very broken C++. For instance, you cannot omit the return type of `main`, and you appear to be mixing `new` and `free` which is asking for trouble. I suggest finding a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to find the problem?

Comment: `if( arrayCopy[i] == 'A' && arrayCopy[i] == 'E'` Clearly, the same character can't be equal to both `'A'` and `'E'` at the same time. The condition is never true.

Comment: I feel like I should just post the whole thing. I truncated a lot of it....

Comment: Best to stick to one problem per question. Pick one problem and make a small program that demonstrates that one problem. We call this a [mcve] The beauty f the MCVE is in making one you very often expose the problem for what it is and figure out how to fix it. Oh and `return` ends the function, so `return arrVowels; free (arrVowels);` never reaches the `free(arrVowels);`. This also exposes a problem with trying to `return` and `free` you free stuff ans obviously it's gone. You'll find better ways to do this, like `std::string`, in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `searchVowels`, you seems to have the following code :

```
        if( arrayCopy[i] == 'A' && arrayCopy[i] == 'E'                  
        && arrayCopy[i] == 'I' && arrayCopy[i] == 'O' &&                
        arrayCopy[i] == 'U' && arrayCopy[i] == 'Y')                     
        {                                                               
                arrVowels[i] = arrayCopy[i];                            
        }
```

How are you expecting the `arrayCopy[i]` to pass the check since it cannot have all vowels at the same time. I think you're looking for an `OR` check here.

```
        if( arrayCopy[i] == 'A' || arrayCopy[i] == 'E'                  
        || arrayCopy[i] == 'I' || arrayCopy[i] == 'O' ||
        arrayCopy[i] == 'U' || arrayCopy[i] == 'Y')                     
        {                                                               
                arrVowels[i] = arrayCopy[i];                            
        }
```

In the above case, it might fill the `arrayVowels` with something if the check passes.

Also, you can make the above code into a function something like `HasVowels()`, which checks if the the `arrayCopy` has a vowel at the ith index and then use it in both `searchVowels` and `searchConsonants`.

One more thing is the usage of "free" in your code.
**In C++, delete operator should only be used either for the pointers pointing to the memory allocated using `new operator`, and `free()` should only be used either for the pointers pointing to the memory allocated using `malloc()` or for a NULL pointer.**

Comment: Okay so I won't use free() then if I don't use malloc(); Thanks mate Also && switch to || got it.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator should be used with the `delete` operator (not with `free`).

You should not delete or free memory that you're returning from a 
function if the return value is intended for use by the caller.

In this example below, the caller of the function (not the 
function itself) allocates the memory and the caller of the function
frees the memory when it is no longer needed.

The `searchVowels` function won't necessarily know when the
caller no longer needs the memory.

In this example below, the `searchVowels` function does not allocate
memory and assumes that memory for the `dest` argument array
and the input string have already been allocated.

```
/* IMPORTANT: This code assumes that SIZE is already defined */

void searchVowels(char* dest, char * inputString) {                                          
    int destIndex;
    int i;

    /* Update this function with other functionality */
    /* as intended */

    destIndex = 0;
    dest[destIndex] = '\0';

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(inputString); i++)                                              
    {                                                                       
        if ((inputString[i] == 'A') || (inputString[i] == 'E')) {
        {   
            if (destIndex < SIZE) {
                dest[destIndex] = inputString[i];
                dest[destIndex+1] = '\0';
                destIndex = destIndex + 1;
            }                                                            
        }                                                               
    }                                                                       
}  

/* From the code that calls searchVowels */

char* result;

try {
    char* result = new char[SIZE];

    searchVowels(result, "TESTAEIOU");

    /* Use the result variable Here */

    delete result;

} catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
  /* new did not allocate memory */
}
```

Comment: So I should be putting in two args for my searchConsonant function? Should I not be trying to return the data and instead set it equal to destIndex[i] and pass it instead by refrence? And does the destIndex make sure I don't add chars I don't want into the pointer?

Comment: Hi  This function uses 2 arguments because it assumes that both the input and destination already have the memory allocated.  This function (as written) does not allocate memory.  In that sense, the responsibility for allocating the memory and deallocating the memory lies with the calling function.  Using this as a convention makes it easier to know which parts of the code should allocate and deallocate.

Comment: Yes - if this is used as a string it should be null-terminated - I added that also

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, it was returning but not setting the data how it should have been. I needed to use the || pipes for the vowels and set up another for loop to check all the conditions. It had nothing to do with freeing up memory.
Here's the code of the function.

```
     char * searchConsonants(char * arrayCopy)                                       
{                                                                               

    char * consonants; consonants = new char[SIZE];                         

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)                                             
    {//I feel like I could make this into a function itself...hmm           
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)                                      
            {                                                               
                    if( arrayCopy[j] != 'A' && arrayCopy[j] != 'E'          
                    && arrayCopy[j] != 'I' && arrayCopy[j] != 'O' &&        
                    arrayCopy[j] != 'U' && arrayCopy[j] != 'Y')             
                    {                                                       
                    consonants[i] = arrayCopy[j];                           
                    ++i;                                                    
                    }                                                       
            }                                                               
    }                                                                       

return consonants;                                                              
}
```